# Arithmetic Operations in AngularJS Bindings

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

So I'm printing out the numerical ratings for three survey questions

```
 {{surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q1rating}}
 {{surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q2rating}}
 {{surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q3rating}}
```

and now I'm trying to find the average rating of the three questions.

I tried this:

```
  {{(surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q1Rating+surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q2Rating+surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q3rating)/3}}
```

and this:

```
  {{((surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q1Rating)+(surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q2Rating)+(surveyDatas.questionsRatings.q3rating))/3}}
```

and niether of them are yielding the correct answer.
The ratings for the three survey questions are 10, so the average score is supposed to be 10+10+10=30/3=10, and the answer I'm getting when I tried the two methods above is 3.3333333. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the code that shows the values being assigned to your 3 vars.

Comment: I actually just realized what the problem was. I accidentally capitalized the "R" is ratings. Sorry about that.